# How to read a text file and insert those values into database using php

Tags: php, mysql, text

I have a text file like this names ernakulam.txt which has content like this:

```
name1
name2
name3
name4
name5
```

I want to insert this value into my Mysql database table named places. Mysql table has fields like this:

```
dist_id  |  name
_________|______
         |
         |
```

In this table field1 (dist_id) should be same for all rows. The dist_id value is 6. How to read those names from text file and insert to Mysql table using php?

Comment: And your try ? any code you have done

Comment: please try `while($dat=fread($res));`

Comment: You can use [file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php), then loop over the array with lines, trim them and insert them into the database using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

$file = '/path/to/ernakulam.txt';
$file_content = file_get_contents($file);
$names = explode("\n", $file_content);
```

and so on